# Codename one/netbeans downloading demos does not work

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

I have downloaded all the demos of codename one, netbeans. I import the projects. No demo works for me. It shows errors missing jar files, and no main classes. How do i fix this?
See in picture.

[showing all errors in downloaded projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiRQP.png)

[showing specific errors after pressing resolve, .jar missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjvMu.png)

Update: 
Codename one settings does not work.
[image: codename 1 setting]

Comment: You need to provide the link(s) for the demos you downloaded.

Comment: True:
https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/

Comment: Re _"Update: Codename one settings does not work"_, that is because you have problems with the project; note the menu entry **"Resolve Project Problems..."**. Once those problems are resolved the entries on the **Codename One** menu will be enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also struggled to get the demos working from the GitHub download, but that is the wrong approach. Shai's answer has already provided the solution, and this post is just expanding on that to clarify the exact steps required in NetBeans.

Step 1 of 3: Install the **CodenameOnePlugin** plugin:

- **Tools > Plugins >** select the **Available Plugins** tab.
- Select and check **CodenameOnePlugin**, then click **Install**.
- The plugin will be installed and you will be invited to restart NetBeans, so do that.

Step 2 of 3: Create one of the **Demos** projects:

- Select **File > New Project**.
- After installing the plugin and restarting NetBeans, in the **New Project** dialog there is a new category named **Codename One** with a sub-category named **Demos**.
- Select **Demos** and then select one of the projects from the **Projects** list such as **CameraDemo** and complete the **New Project** wizard:

[image: selectProject]

- Open one of the Java source files. You will see that there are no errors for unresolved imports.

Step 3 of 3: Run the demo project you just created.

- Select the demo project you chose to create in the **Projects** tab, then press **F6** to run it.

That's all there is to it! No downloading is needed, apart from installing the plugin. However, I did hit a couple of very minor issues:

1. During project creation some of the projects have the same default name of **Demo**. Just pick another name.
2. There is a build problem with certain projects such as **Charts**:

> Unsupported source/binary format (in Charts)
>
> The project source/binary format is older than minimal supported one
>   (1.6).

The solution is simple:

- Select the project in the **Projects** tab.
- Right-click and select **Properties**.
- Select **Sources** and then update the value of **Source/Binary** format to **1.8**.

Comment: It's not about the demos that are already there. It's about source code files that are not contained in the demos.

Comment: @stsesn I am puzzled by your comment that it is  _"about source code files that are not contained in the demos"_. To be clear, is your current problem that you followed the approach described in my post above yet there is source missing for the demos? Everything worked perfectly for me - the source code is in the demos, and they build and run with no issues. Am I misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using File -> New -> Codename One -> Demos instead.

Otherwise you need to place the right jars into the projects as they aren't included in git: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-setup-codename-one-demo-from-git.html

Comment: Thank you. However, there are some demos on the internet, that there are no JAR files in the default demos inside codename one. Where do i find the "right" .jar files for them? Bar code scanner is one example, there are some more.
https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/

Comment: Sorry I linked to the wrong article I meant to link to this which answers the question: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-setup-codename-one-demo-from-git.html I'll update the answer

Comment: Alas, codename one settings is not working for projects that are not contained in the demos. I am updating the original question with the image.

Comment: Copy the jar files from a new blank project most specifically CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar in the project root. Once it's there netbeans will identify the project as a Codename One project then Codename One Settings will work.